# How to close Item count menu

Tags: 3d-view

I pressed <kbd>ctrl</kbd> <kbd>shift</kbd> <kbd>A</kbd> on a particle mesh and this poped up

[image]

I don't know what it is called might be an array mode Operator from looking up in key-bindings.

Now my problem I can't close this menu. I tried pressing the same key and more pops up. I also tried <kbd>alt</kbd><kbd>shift</kbd><kbd>A</kbd> but it does't close.

This is how it looks now.

[image]

Comment: Could you please give us a bit more informations? Which mode, which particle type? Ctrl Shift A does nothing here. But could be that i am in the wrong mode. I expect an addon here though. Since there is no default key map entry for shift ctrl a that is connected with particles.

Comment: This looks like a custom interface introduced by an add-on. Which add-ons are you using ?

Comment: @Gorgious Can you let me know if there anything called an Array Mode Operator in Blender? or is it an addon? I could see something called Array Mode Operator when I search in keymap in preferences. I think that's causing the issue.

Comment: This is definitely added by an add-on. You can check enabled addons in the preferences